# For loop can only process two steps

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried get the numbers in l2 start from the maximum one, and each pair of them do subtraction should more or equal than 2. That situation only works if l1 has more than 1 element. So for l2=[2,1,8,3,6,4], expecting output is l1=[8,6,4] since 4-3 <2 the 4th largest 3 will not be taken. Here is my code

```
l2=[2,1,8,3,6,4]
l1=[]
def check():        
    i = max(l2)
    l2.remove(i)
    if len(l1)>1:
        for number in l1:
            if (abs(number - i)) < int(2):
                break;
    else:
        l1.append(i)
        check()
```

But the output is [8,6].Can anyone tell me how to correct that?

Comment: I do not understand your requirements.

Comment: Where is `lst` defined?

Comment: Sorry maybe it is not clear. First add the maximum number a in l2 to l1, then for the second largest in l2 b, if a-b>=2, add b to l1. Repeat the step until a n-m<2 occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want is this:

```
l2=[2,1,8,3,6,4]
l1=[]
def check():
    i = max(l2)
    l2.remove(i)
    if len(l1) > 0:
        for number in l1:
            if abs(number - i) < 2:
                return l1
    l1.append(i)
    check()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your problem:

```
  1 l2 = [2, 1, 8, 3, 6, 4]
  2 
  3 def generate_l1(l):
  4     copy = list(l)
  5     result = []
  6     result.append(max(copy))
  7     copy.remove(max(copy))
  8     while result[len(result) - 1] - max(copy) >= 2:
  9         result.append(max(copy))
 10         copy.remove(max(copy))                                                                                                                                                   
 11     return result
 12 
 13 print(generate_l1(l2))
```

The function `generate_l1` produces the expected list from the given list `l` while not modifying the original list `l2`